# Android TimePickerDialog and DateTimePicker info is too small

Tags: android, timepickerdialog

My TimePickerDialog (Date too) is showing the time in very small format...

[Dialog Too Small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71m2F.jpg)

I tried to create a custom theme, but it doesn't work either as I don't know what property to set.

```
<style name="DateAndTimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I found how to solve this problem:

You just need to set the textSize and buttonStyle:

```
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DateAndTimePickerButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textSize">54sp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DateAndTimePickerButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DateAndTimePickerButtonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

I hope it help someone!